# Showing the Artifact metadata tab in Nexus 2.1.1?

Tags: nexus

In browsing Sonatype Nexus Professional Edition, Version 2.1.1, I want to be able to see the artifact metadata.

Reading http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/_editing_artifact_metadata.html  the picture shows there should be a right hand panel showing the Artifact metadata tab.

Is there something needed in configuration to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [figure 5.7](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-browsing.html#fig-using-dependencies), you have to select an artifact (for example a jar file) in the tree view to get the right-side pane to show up.

The metadata pane is provided by the nexus-custom-metadata-plugin. Current Nexus Pro distribution includes it as an optional plugin. See [Installing additional plugins](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-additional-plugins.html) on how to install an optional plugin.

Comment: That shows the information tab alright, thanks. My mail was a little misleading, I want to see the metadata, but assumed it was the information tab rather than the metadata tab, sorry. I want to see the tab in the picture http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/_editing_artifact_metadata.html. I will update my question sorry.

Comment: @boardtc I updated my answer wrt. nexus-custom-metadata-plugin.